# PHP strtotime with multiple variables

Tags: php, variables, date, time, strtotime

This is my PHP code:

```
$timestamp2 = strtotime('13:30 04/12/2013');
```

But, I want to put the these variables in this code:

```
        $mi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mi']);
        $ho = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ho']);
        $da = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['da']);
        $mo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mo']);
        $ye = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ye']);
```

So for example:

```
$timestamp2 = strtotime('$mi:$ho $mo/$da/$ye');
```

I tried already multiple possibilities with quotes and etc.. But it didn't have any succes. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a question here? If you're just trying to use `strtotime` on all the variables, put them in an array and run them through a `foreach`

Comment: Actually, my solution isn't what you are looking for. Didn't realize those were each dateparts and not dates by themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime) does what you want, just be careful with the parameter order. Something like this should work:

```
$timestamp2 = mktime($ho, $mi, 0, $mo, $da, $ye);
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can indicate that you accept the answer with the checkmark below the upvote/downvote arrows buttons.

Comment: I know, but I couldn't yet at that moment (had to wait 5 min.).. :P